# There's a tag called "judgement"

Tags: discussion, tags

Just a heads up in case anyone is willing and able to change it to its appropriate spelling of "judgment".

Answer (score 3):

Both spellings are actually valid in the context of a multi-regional site like this one. Note the Wikipedia page is titled '[judgement](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgement)' and See [here](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/judgement.html) for a note on how the mess got started.

Which variant we use as the canonical tag name can be discussed but this not a case of a simple miss-spelling.

**Edit:** I have done a mass rename on the tag to reflect the [more common spelling in a theological context](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgment_%28law%29#Spelling). You may now find it at [judgment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judgment).

Comment: Ah, interesting, I didn't know that this was an alternate spelling. Would a better suggestion for this case be to have both tags "judgment" and "judgement" point to the same list of posts? Given the link you sent me, does that mean that we would have tags for both "color" and "colour"? In programming (which includes HTML page development) you would only have "color", no matter where you are from.

Comment: @RaphaelRosch I think it is un-necessary to have both spellings even as synonyms because the tag complete system shows the options and only experienced taggers can create new entries, so most will just tag with whatever we have. I also think dropping the 'e' in the canonical is probably the way to go even though that is a recent innovation even in American parlance; in the mean time I answered just to point out that this is not a cut and dry case of a miss-spelled tag.

Answer (score 2):

[It's back again!](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judgement)

I guess that it's not set up as a synonym? Maybe it should be now?

Comment: I've merged those questions into the canonical one. Hopefully it won't be necessary to and a synonym for a spelling issue, but if it happens again maybe we should. I think the trick is we have to keep any questions from using it long enough that the tag cleanup kicks in and actually removes the tag so it won't show in the auto-complete and low-rep users cannot possibly misuse it. I suspect that is what happened last time: we picked up a new question with it before the cleanup would have happened.

Answer (score 0):

With stuff like this, please simply suggest an edit on the posts in question. The incorrect tag will age off automatically. Thanks.

Comment: Do I need to have a minimum reputation for that? Or do you mean that I should go to every question tagged "judgement" and suggest each OP change the tag? (I don't think that might earn me many friends.) I know that to create a tag you need a certain amount of reputation, for example, and I definitely don't have the required amount, so I doubt I could delete one, or even modify someone else's post to tag it appropriately.

Comment: I would have to disagree here; if it was a handful of posts with a miss-spelled tag this would be correct but the case @RaphaelRosch  pointed out was nearly 30 questions and our canonical version on the tag. Taking it to meta for discussion (he seems to have been unaware that the spelling isn't a cut and dry issue) and if agreed upon a mass rename (which I have now done) is the right course of action. Suggesting 27 edits for this and bumping those posts would have been disruptive.